# What is the difference between git diff origin/master ... origin/branch and git diff origin/master...origin/branch?

Tags: git

Git diff seems to return different changes when comparing:

```
git diff origin/master ... origin/branch
git diff origin/master...origin/branch
```

What's the difference between the two? For those that can't see the difference in the first command, the `...` is buffered by spaces.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually the "dots" notation is for specifying ranges and full doc on that is available in `git log --help` section "Specifying Revisions" and mostly used for listings like `git log`.

Briefly speaking you have two branches started from commit a:

```
a - b - c (master)
\d - e (topic)
```

`git log master..topic` will show you commits that are reachable from topic but not reachable from master, effectively "d" and "e"

`git log topic..master` will show you commits that are reachable from master but not reachable from topic, effectively "b" and "c"

Now `git log master...topic` (note three dots) will show you all commits that are reachable from either master or topic but not from both, effectively b,c,d and e

The diff though is working with two points of history, not the ranges so for example the notation

```
git diff topic master
```

or

`git diff topic..master`

should return the same result, i.e. the diff between the tips of the branches specified
The three dots notation

`git diff topic...master`

should show the changes that occurred in master since the topic branch was forked off of it

As Jan pointed out the notation with the three dots surrounded by spaces is understood by git as the difference between the tips of the branches (like no dots or two dots) in case when HEAD is pointing to the same commit as one of the branches of interest. In cases when HEAD is neither topic or master it will result in three way diff.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I've retracted the downvote, but still think that the talk about log is extraneous. I've also now checked the behaviour and is as I suspected -- `git diff A ... B` where neither `A` nor `B` equal `HEAD` gives a 3-way diff.

Comment: I saw many cases of people being confused by the differences between log and diff and the dots notation usage, that's why i decided to explain the difference. As for the three way diff - it s a good observation, I actually never used that before.

Answer (score 2):

The correct syntax is without spaces and does diff from common ancestor to the right branch.

With spaces it should be an error, because `...` is neither revision nor path, but the argument parser takes it as synonym for HEAD. Probably side-effect of the fact, that `...branch` means `HEAD...branch` and `branch...` means `branch...HEAD`. Together with the fact that git diff can take any number of arguments and produces n-way diffs when given more than 2 *distinct* arguments. I've checked and indeed `git diff A ... B` produces a 3-way diff when neither `A` nor `B` point to the same revision as `HEAD`.